# Monit and java process

Tags: java, monit

I'm trying to use monit to monitor a java process.  The monit file for the process is as follows:

```
check process xyz pidfile /tmp/xyz.pid
start program = "/bin/bash -c 'source /home/.bashrc; source /home/xyzprog/setup.sh; /home/xyzprog/xyz start'"
stop program = "/bin/bash -c '/home/xyzprog/xyz stop'"
```

This process works fine if i start with with

```
sudo monit start xyz
```

But fails completely if when i start monit in daemon mode.

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: What do you mean by `fails`? What errors are you getting?

Comment: 'sfs' start: /bin/bash

[UTC Jul 23 06:57:35] debug    : 'xyz' Error testing process id [17427] -- No such process

[UTC Jul 23 06:57:35] debug    : 'xyz' Error testing process id [17427] -- No such process

Comment: Basically the process doesn't start.  It starts fine when monit is not set in daemon mode, but it doesn't work from the daemon.  I have no idea why.  Now this is a java process, so it depends on some environment variables, which i handle by sourcing a few setup scripts in the bash call.  This should work in theory, and does, but not in daemon mode.

Comment: I got a partial solution when i replaced ${PWD} in one of the setup scripts with the full path.  However, the process fails to restart if i take it down and have monit call start.  That pretty much defeats the purpose for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I realized that some of the scripts were based on running in the home directory of the process, so i update the start program to the follow:

```
check process xyz pidfile /tmp/xyz.pid
start program = "cd /home/xyzprog; /bin/bash -c 'source /home/.bashrc; source /home/xyzprog/setup.sh; /home/xyzprog/xyz start'"
stop program = "/bin/bash -c '/home/xyzprog/xyz stop'"
if failed host 192.168.1.103 port 8080 protocol http with timeout 20 seconds for 1 cycle then restart
```

I simply added 'cd /home/xyzprog' to the start program and it worked!  I killed the process and it came right back.